# Creating a basic custom Cordova Plugin

Tags: java, android, angularjs, cordova-plugins

I am quite new in cordova and android native code

I had created my own plugin by using plugman.

```
plugman create --name myCustomPlugin --plugin_id myCustomPlugin --plugin_version 1.0
```

plugman had generated all the needed files for me to get started.

js file `www/myCustomPlugin.js`

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

exports.coolMethod = function(arg0, success, error) {
  exec(success, error, "myCustomPlugin", "coolMethod", [arg0]);
};
```

java file `src/android/myCustomPlugin.java`, method execute

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if (action.equals("coolMethod")) {
        String message = args.getString(0);
        this.coolMethod(message, callbackContext);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void coolMethod(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
        callbackContext.success(message);
    } else {
        callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
    }
}
```

The question is: 
On the cordova project js file. How do I call myCustomPlugin? and how do I know that it is working?

I am using angular in my cordova project, let say my controller is like this:

```
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
     // how to call myCustomPlugin here?
});
```

My motive is just to learn how to call and how it work only, maybe after click it will do a native alert or open native view or something.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

**www/myCustomPlugin.js**

```
var MyCustomPlugin {
    coolMethod : function(arg0, success, error) {
        exec(success, error, "myCustomPlugin", "coolMethod", [arg0]);
    }
}

module.exports = MyCustomPlugin
```

And in your js client just:

```
MyCustomPlugin.coolMethod("Arg1", function(){}, function(){});
```

Cordova will inject JavaScript file for you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: when i installed this plugin to my cordova project, and then call it. it says `MyCustomPlugin` is undefined. do i need to include the plugin js file in my index.html?